# PostGis: Calculating distance in different methods, What's the difference?

Tags: postgis, distance, spherical-geometry

What is the most efficient (or just "best practice") way to calculate distance between 2 points, assuming we are on 2D world without big circle etc. phenomenon (distances up to 300 meters).

**Method 1:**

```
SELECT ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lon1 lat1)',4326)::GEOGRAPHY, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lon2 lat2)',4326)::GEOGRAPHY);
```

**Method 2:**

```
SELECT ST_Distance(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lon1 lat1)',4326), 26986), ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(lon2 lat2)',4326), 26986));
```

assuming 26986 is the correct metric SRID for the location.

**Method 3:**

Using `ST_Distance_Spheroid`

Comment: One slightly tangential comment - you can use st_point directly instead of st_geomfromtext('POINT...

Answer (score 5):

If you're happy with the characteristics of your projection, you should just use `ST_Distance(geometry, geometry)`. In your example you seem to be in UTM, which is a pretty good projection, so why not? It's much much less CPU intensive than the geodetic functions `ST_Distance(geography, geography)`.

(Note that `ST_Distance_Spheroid()` just calls into the same code line as `ST_Distance(geography, geography)` so there's no point in talking about them as distinct methods. The function is still around as a backwards compatibility shim for folks who don't want to cast to geography.)

If you are in a project like mercator (or web mercator) then you would definitely *not* want to use 2D distance, since those projections are very poor for distance measurement everywhere more than a few degrees from the equator.

The nice thing is, you can easily compare the results of different methods in one SQL statement.

```
WITH d AS (
SELECT ST_Distance(ST_Transform(a.geom, 26986), ST_Transform(b.geom, 26986)) as d_geom, 
       ST_Distance(a.geom::geography, b.geom::geography) as d.geog
FROM mytable a, mytable b
LIMIT 100
)
SELECT d_geom, d_geog, 
       abs(d_geog-d_geom) as diff,
       100*abs(d_geog-d_geom)/d_geog as pct_diff
FROM d;
```